# signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR) librealm-jni.so

Tags: android, realm

It happens in all the Android versions and does not show anything but the logs below.

Is any hint I can deal with for it?

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> package.name <<<

backtrace:
  #00  pc 000000000011eb0a  /data/app/package.name/lib/arm/librealm-jni.so
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded the realm from 3.1.3 to 5.13.0 and it was gone.

In the Gradle file, update the realm version number.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
       ...
    }

    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin: 5.13.0
        ...
    }
}
```